# Using latexdiff with IEEEeqnarray environment

Tags: ieeetran, ieee-style, latexdiff

**Note:** I asked this question on Stackoverflow a month ago, but I'm deleting it and re-posting it here because I got no answers there.

---

I recently discovered `latexdiff`, and it has generally been a satisfaction.
However, I have been encountering problems using it with the `IEEEeqnarray` environment from the `IEEEtrantools` package (which I use a lot).
Here is a minimal example of this problem.

File `a.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
a^2 &=& b
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

Some text.

More text.

Even more text.

\end{document}
```

File `b.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}

\begin{document}

Some text.

More text.

Even more text.

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
a^2 &=& b
\end{IEEEeqnarray*}

\end{document}
```

Output of `latexdiff a.tex b.tex` (I'll spare you the preamble):

```latex
\begin{document}

\DIFdelbegin %DIFDELCMD < \begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
%DIFDELCMD < %%%
\DIFdel{a^2 }%DIFDELCMD < &%%%
\DIFdel{=}%DIFDELCMD < & %%%
\DIFdel{b
}%DIFDELCMD < \end{IEEEeqnarray*}
%DIFDELCMD < 

%DIFDELCMD < %%%
\DIFdelend Some text.

More text.

Even more text.
\DIFaddbegin 

\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{rCl}
\DIFadd{a^2 }&\DIFadd{=}& \DIFadd{b
}\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\DIFaddend 

\end{document}
```

So it seems that `latexdiff` is not recognizing that `IEEEeqnarray` is a math environment since it is removing it, giving compilation errors such as:

```latex
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.31 \DIFdel{a^2 }
                  %DIFDELCMD < &%%%
```

Is there a way to tell it that `IEEEeqnarray` is a math environment?
If not, what solutions would you suggest?

Thanks!

---

**Update:**
I tried to modify the `latexdiff` script itself by adding `IEEEeqnarray` to the list of `eqnarray`-like environments.
This makes `latexdiff` treat it correctly as a math environment, but it raises another issue:
`IEEEeqnarray` takes the mandatory alignment argument (`rCl` in the examples above), but `latexdiff` does not recognize that, leading to output of the form:

```latex
\DIFaddbegin 
\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{\DIFadd{rCl}}
\DIFadd{a^2 }&\DIFadd{=}& \DIFadd{b
}\end{IEEEeqnarray*}
\DIFaddend
```

As you can see, the argument to `IEEEeqnarray` gets changed to `\DIFadd{rCl}` which leads to compilation errors:

```latex
! Class IEEEtran Error: Invalid character in column specifications.

See the IEEEtran class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.43 \begin{IEEEeqnarray*}{\DIFadd{rCl}}
```

Any ideas? I'm not really familiar with perl to comfortably tweak the script much more than that.

Comment: I don't think there is an easy solution, as latexdiff does not expect maths environments to have arguments. I will look into this on the latexdiff side (I am the author). If you are always using {rCl} as your argument, then you can probably make a work around by defining using \newenvironment to define IEEEeqnarrayrCl and declaring this to latexdiff as an array envirnment using the --config option: --config MATHARRENV=(?:eqnarray|align|alignat|gather|multline|flalign|IEEEeqnarrayrCl)[*]? ).  But this possibly implies having to rewrite history and won't work if you like to use different args

Comment: Feel free to add this as an issue on https://github.com/ftilmann/latexdiff/

Comment: @frederik I generally use more than just {rCl}, but I guess I could do something of the sort for my most-commonly-used args. I will add this as an issue. Thanks for your answer!